# NodeJS Printing object json to html

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to print a NodeJS object as simple json in EJS template file.

I am defining the object in NodeJs and trying to print it in EJS file like this:

```
<%= JSON.stringify(objName) %>
```

This is encoding double quotes (") is some format and giving me output like this:

```
{&#34;_id&#34;:&#34;5c3587b78ff1928c5124bf6d&#34;,&#34;name&#34;:&#34;Sourabh Bajaj&#34;,&#34;role&#34;:10,&#34;roleName&#34;:&#34;InstituteAdmin&#34;,&#34;mobileNumber&#34;:&#34;+919166677890&#34;,&#34;email&#34;:&#34;sorbhb@gmail.com&#34;,&#34;mobileVerified&#34;:true,&#34;emailVerified&#34;:true,&#34;instituteId&#34;:&#34;5c3586308ff1928c5124bf24&#34;,&#34;passwordResetKey&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;success&#34;:true,&#34;errorCode&#34;:200};
```

If I don't stringify it, it give me `[Object object]` as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. EJS template somehow encodes double quotes when you use <%= %>.

If you don't want that, use <%- %> tags instead.